# How to color correct a mosaic raster

Tags: sentinel-2

I am building a composite image to create a wetland predictor variable and I will then run RF to classify wetlands.

The first step is to mosaic Sentinel-2 images (4 bands, RGBI) and then create a composite with other LiDAR derivatives. The issue I am getting is that when I stitch the Sentinel rasters together, they aren't seamless. Should I run the RF per scene? I am worried the colour differences in each scene will impact the model's ability to classify.